# Can IE browser compatibility mode be changed depended on the Webpage visited?

Tags: internet-explorer, post, cross-browser

We have a POS (Point of Sale) system which accesses the internet with IE8. But, the browser is set to work in IE7 compatibility. There is a particular training page for our employees provided by a third party website, which is accessed through our INtranet. When the 3rd party site is accessed, a POST is done to log the user in with their work credentials. However, this site renders wrong in IE7 compatibility. We would like this page to be rendered in IE8, and for the intranet to be rendered IE7. The user themselves cannot change compatibility. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the IE8 browser to work as IE8. Then in the intranet page, try adding this to your meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Then the browser will render the intranet page like IE7, and when going to the third party site, it should render as IE8 page since the browser version is IE8.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont think I am able to change the compatibility mode on the POS systems for other reasons (reasons im not clear) so I want to force only this webpage

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Simply add the appropriate `X-UA-Compatible` flag to the top of your code:

To force IE7 mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE7">
```

To force IE into the best available standards mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

This line is added to the `<head>` section of your HTML code, along with any other meta tags you may have.

It is also possible to add the `X-UA-Compatible` value as an HTTP header, which may be helpful if you can't change the existing HTML code.

Please note, however, that IE7-compatibility mode is **not** an identical copy of IE7. There are differences between them which mean that some sites that look okay in one may not work quite right in the other. It is important to test in both if you're going to do this.

In some cases this compatibility mode feature may be helpful in saving you from having to fix existing code when upgrading your browser. However in most cases it's a better option to fix the site so that it works correctly in the updated browser. The changes required are often fairly minor (especially since IE7 and later; it's a bigger issue for IE5 or IE6, but that's not what you asked), and is often not much different from the effort of making sure it works in compatibility mode.

Comment: how exactly would I add to header? I am not too versed in HTTP but would I add the http header in the POST method?

Comment: @user2449109 - that would depend on what server software you're using. It would require some kind of server config setup for Apache, IIS, or whatever else you may be running on. I could google some links for you, but if you're not comfortable with it the HTML meta tag option is probably better for you.